# What key metrics should a CIO rely on to gauge the extent of IT risk exposure?

Tags: business-risk, risk-management, metrics

*Note - This was originally asked in another Area51 proposal, which has since been deleted.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [ISACA CGEIT](http://www.isaca.org/Certification/CGEIT-Certified-in-the-Governance-of-Enterprise-IT/Pages/default.aspx?utm_source=multiple&utm_medium=multiple&utm_content=friendly&utm_campaign=cgeit) (Certificate in Governance of Enterprise IT) the key categories are:

1. Respond to business requirements in
   alignment with business strategy
2. Respond to governance requirements
   in line with board direction
3. Ensure satisfaction of end users
   with service offerings and service
   levels
4. Optimise the use of information
5. Create IT agility
6. Define how business functional and
   control requirements are translated
   in effective and efficient automated
   solutions
7. Acquire and maintain integrated and
   standardised application systems
8. Acquire and maintain an integrated
   and standardised IT infrastructure
9. Acquire and maintain IT skills that
   respond to IT strategy
10. Ensure mutual satisfaction of third
     party relationships
11. Ensure seamless integration of
     applications into business
     processes
12. Ensure transparency and
     understanding of IT cost, benefits,
     strategy, policies and service
     levels
13. Ensure proper use and performance
     of the applications and technology
     solutions
14. **Account for and protect all IT
     assets**
15. Optimise the IT infrastructure,
         resources and capabilities
16. Reduce solution and service
     delivery defects and rework
17. **Protect the achievement of IT
     objectives**
18. Establish clarity of business
     impact of risks to IT objectives
     and resources
19. **Ensure that critical and
     confidential information is
     withheld from those who should not
     have access to it**
20. **Ensure that automated business
     transactions and information
     exchanges can be trusted**
21. **Ensure that IT services and 
     infrastructure can properly resist 
     and recover from failures due to 
     error, deliberate attack or 
     disaster**
22. **Ensure minimum business impact in
     the event of a IT service
     disruption or change**
23. **Make sure that IT services are
     available as required**
24. Improve IT's cost efficiency and
     its contribution to business
     profitability
25. Deliver projects on time and on
     budget, meeting quality standards
26. **Maintain the integrity of 
     information and processing 
     infrastructure**
27. **Ensure IT compliance with laws,
     regulations and contracts**
28. Ensure that IT demonstrates cost
     efficient service quality,
     continuous improvement and
     readiness for future change

Interestingly, you will see that only nine of those are really to do with IT security, and of those, five are around resilience, so the CIO's view of risk is not the same as an IT security professional's.

So realistically, the stats required would be in reference to:

protecting assets - attacks detected on assets vs successful attacks
access control - breaches of access control, failures to include users in policy etc
trust of automated processes - audit flags, control failures
Ensuring business continuity - successful testing of BC/DR plans
Reduction of impact - cost analysis post attacks (successful or otherwise)
Compliance - audit/regulator findings

Comment: Nice answer... BUT most of it is not metrics :). Also, I think most of the metrics that ARE there are more a question of "how well did we survive that attack", or "how bad are the attacks". I'm not sure it really says much about the risk exposure... (i.e. *before* the attack or misuse...)

Answer (score 3):

- # of incidents per year, by type, in positive integers
- Time/resources needed to handle (investigate, clean up, analysis/review/post-mortem, etc) incidents, in number of man hours (each incident should have their own corresponding data)
- Coverage (as a percentage) across metastructure and infostructure in terms of forensics, log management, incident response process/program management, and incident handler training
- Quality of forensics, log management, incident response process/program management and incident handler training, by category (info/metastructure) and sub-category (e.g. per-app, per-BU, per-data-center, etc), as gauged by an external assessor (once per year, measured as some sort of scale that can be trended over time, probably 1 to 100 and grades but not like FISMA)